Minimum Cost to Make Array Elements Equal with Prefix Operations
Given an array of integers arr, the objective is to make all elements equal by applying operations. Each operation allows you to choose a prefix of the array and an integer x. Adding x to each element within the chosen prefix incurs a cost of |x| (absolute value).
Find the minimum total cost required to make all elements in the array equal.
Input: arr = [1, 2, 1, 5]
Output: 6
Explanation:

Operation 1: Prefix [1, 2] with x = -1 -> Cost = 1 (becomes [0, 1, 1, 5])
Operation 2: Prefix [1, 2, 1] with x = 4 -> Cost = 4 (becomes [4, 5, 5, 5])
Operation 3: Prefix [1] with x = 1 -> Cost = 1 (becomes [5, 5, 5, 5])
Total Cost: 1 + 4 + 1 = 6

What is an efficient algorithm to calculate the minimum cost for making all elements in arr equal, considering the given operations and constraints?

maybe add the absolute values of the differences between adjacent values (|1-2| + |2-1| + |1-5|)

The question is fine (I did not downvote), but why are you asking? Does it smell a bit like asking someone to do a task that you ought to do your self, for example homework? Just curious.

There is this observation:
If two consecutive values, [] and [+1] differ by some value , it is clear that an operation is needed on the prefix A[0..] so to cover for that difference of . There is no other way to make these two values equal. Any other operation would keep the difference the same.
So the absolute difference that each consecutive pair has is a cost that needs to be included. The sum of these costs, i.e. differences, will be the total cost.
    public static int getCost(int[] a) {
        int cost = 0;
        for (int i = a.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            cost += Math.abs(a[i] - a[i+1]);
        }
        return cost;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 1, 5};
        System.out.println("cost is " + getCost(a)); // cost is 6
    }


Let us take an example, [a,b,c,d]
and calculate the differences between the adjacent elements and then add that difference up to the prefix length.
differences are -> b-a, c-b, d-c
add b-a to prefix length=1
therefore array will become b,b,c,d
add c-b to prefix length=2
therefore array will become c,c,c,d
add d-c to prefix length=3
therefore array will become d,d,d,d
all elements will become equal in a minimum total sum of operations of |b-a|+|c-b|+|d-c|
